# How to clone the metadata of documentA and set on documentB?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, metadata, clone, word-pdf

We are using SharePoint Online. I have some document library with Word documents. I created some logic where I convert a Word document to PDF. I would like to write some logic in powershell to clone the metadata of the Word document and set on the PDF document. How to this? Is this for example possible with pnp powershell?

Something like this:

```
#get metadata of documentA
$documentA = Get-PnPListItem -List "TestKH" -Id 1 -Fields "Title","DocumentStatus"

#set metadata of documentB
Set-PnPListItem -List "TestKH" -Identity 2 -Values $documentA.FieldValues
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file metadata of automatically generated by System can not be cloned to another file. For example: **GUID, ID, File Size**.

I suggest you can create **MS Flow** to achieve your design.

—————————————————— **Updated Answer** ————————————————

**Execute the following PowerShell script to copy the file metadata to another document.**

[image]

- **Get the data of the FileA：**

  $SiteURL= "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/projects"

  Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

  $LibName = "Documents"

  $Fields = Get-PnPField -List $LibName

  $FileA= (Get-PnPListItem -List $LibName -Id 38 -Fields "ID","Title","FileStatus","Body")

  Write-Host ""

  Write-Host "ID :"$FileA["ID"] -ForegroundColor Yellow

  Write-Host "Title :"$FileA["Title"]

  Write-Host "Status :"$FileA["FileStatus"]

  Write-Host "Body :"$FileA["Body"]

  Write-Host "—————————————————————————" -BackgroundColor Cyan

[image]

- **Copy data to FileB：**

  Set-PnPListItem -List $LibNAme -Id 40 -Values @{"Title" = $FileA["Title"]; "FileStatus"=$FileA["FileStatus"];"Body"=$FileA["Body"]}
  [image]

Comment: Thank you EchoDu_MSFT, It was just an example. I dont want to clone the ID. I remove it from my example. I would like to avoid MS Flow.

Comment: Hi, Jackson. I have updated my answer, hope this helps you. Have a nice day!